# Smarty issue with {if} inside another tag

Tags: php, smarty

I built plugin of create forms:

```
function smarty_function_form(array $parameters, Smarty_Internal_Template $smarty) {
    $form = new Form($parameters);
    $smarty->form_object = $form;
    return $form->output_opentag();
}
```

When I call it and use "if" tag inside, I am getting syntax error and "too many shorthand attributes" error.

I use it like that:

```
{form name="the_name" {if $var == 5}class="active"{/if} method="post" action=""}
```

If I remove "if" tag it's working.
How to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Does `{form name="the_name" class=$var==5?"active":null method="post" action=""}` work?

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE No, same error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest a Smarty tag or block inside a tag. There is a very simple solution to your problem: move the `{if}` before the `{form}` tag:

```
{assign var=class value=''}
{if $var == 5}
    {assign var=class val=active}
{/if}
{form name="the_name" class=$class method="post" action=""}
```

Then, in the PHP code of the `{form}` plugin you can skip generating the `class` attribute if the value of the `class` parameter is empty and you don't want to generate something like `class=""` (which is harmless by the way).